# how to select the second row if the first row in empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-query-store

how to select the second row in Sql server query if the first row is empty. I have 3 tables

1. **Users**
2. **sites**
3. **siteUser**

A **user** can be assigned to multiple **sites** and a **site** can have multiple **users** but now i want to get only **one user for each site** but if the first user doesn't have a mobile number that start with +01 i have to get the second user assigned to that site but him also if he doesn't have i have to select the 3rd. please help

Comment: Show us your sql tables and what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives first registered user with phone number starts with +01 for each site

```
select s.name, u.*
from site s
outer apply (
                select top(1) * 
                    from user u 
                    where u.phone like '+01%' 
                    and u.id in (select userId FROM siteUser su WHERE su.SiteId = s.Id)
                    order by u.registrationDate
            ) as u
```

Comment: Thanks #Ruslam K. , i can get the first user rows for each site but if the first user doesn't have a number how can I get the second row of user that is assigned to the same site? following the scrip you sent

Comment: `but if the first user doesn't have a number ` in this query is impossible. If there is no users in this site with such phone numbers, you will get NULL in `u.*` columns.

Comment: Thanks #Ruslam K. it working and I understand. sorry for that I am new.